# Image doesn't load when converting from FXML to JAVA

Tags: java, javafx, imageview, fxml

I have converted a FXML file to Java and everything works except one image

```
import java.io.File;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.shape.StrokeType;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
 public class Screen extends Application {
@Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage){
        primaryStage.setTitle("Player Screen");
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        Text coins = new Text();
        coins.setStrokeWidth(0.0);
        coins.setStrokeType(StrokeType.OUTSIDE);
        GridPane.setColumnIndex(coins, 1);
        coins.setId("coins");
        coins.setText("11");
        coins.setWrappingWidth(41.46875);
```

This is the code part of the image:

```
        ImageView imageTile = new ImageView();
        imageTile.setPickOnBounds(true);
        imageTile.setFitWidth(200.0);
        GridPane.setColumnIndex(imageTile, 17);
        imageTile.setFitHeight(150.0);
        GridPane.setRowIndex(imageTile, 2);
        imageTile.setPreserveRatio(true);
        File file = new File("/excommunicationTile1.jpg");
        Image image = new Image(file.toURI().toString());
        imageTile.setImage(image);
```

Both the image and the css file are in the same folder so i don't understand why it loads the css information but not the image.

```
        grid.getChildren().add(coins);
        grid.getChildren().add(imageTile);
        Scene scene = new Scene(grid,546,200);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/style.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `File file = new File("/excommunicationTile1.jpg");`
to

```
InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/excommunicationTile1.jpg")
```